# Column exported to CSV as series of lists of strings, on read Pandas interprets as just series of strings

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python -- I'm doing some text pre-processing and am trying to export csv files which include a column that is a series of lists of strings.

```py
data['Lemmas']

0                                                 [require]
1                               [speak, gentleman, wk, ago]
2         [material, come, soft, plastic, st, use, pste,...
3                               [send, email, confirmation]
```

```py
type(data['Lemmas'][0])

list
```

When reading this csv, Pandas interprets this column as a Series of strings.

```py
0                                               ['require']
1                       ['speak', 'gentleman', 'wk', 'ago']
2         ['material', 'come', 'soft', 'plastic', 'st', ...
3                         ['send', 'email', 'confirmation']
```

```py
type(data_verbatims['Lemmas'][0])

str
```

I've been able to get around this by doing some clunky string manipulation, but there has to be a better way to either export/read this column correctly, or transform it back to the original structure.

```py
import string

lemmas=[]

for words in data_verbatims['Lemmas']:
    for char in words:                 
        if char in string.punctuation:
            words = words.replace(char, '')
    lemmas.append(words)

lemmas = pd.Series(lemmas)
lemmas = lemmas.apply(lambda x: x.split())
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of desired output?

Comment: look at `ast.literal_eval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly we can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html) here:

```
                                          Lemmas
0                                    ['require']
1            ['speak', 'gentleman', 'wk', 'ago']
2  ['material', 'come', 'soft', 'plastic', 'st']
3              ['send', 'email', 'confirmation']

type(df['Lemmas'][0])

#Out
str
```

---

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['Lemmas'] = df['Lemmas'].apply(literal_eval)

                                Lemmas
0                            [require]
1          [speak, gentleman, wk, ago]
2  [material, come, soft, plastic, st]
3          [send, email, confirmation]
```

```
type(df['Lemmas'][0])

#Out
list
```